# Pass in function with default parameters

Tags: python

I have a function in Python `f(a, b)` and I am trying to define a new function `g` that takes in `f` with one argument already set, something like `g(f(a = 5))`. This would be a simple example:

```
def sum(a, b):
   return a+b

def g(x, f):
   return f(x)
```

And I want to be able to evaluate `g(5, sum(b=0))`. How do I do that?

Comment: not sure I am following, whats wrong with `def f(x): return g(5,x)`?

Comment: `sum(b=0)` what do you mean by this? what is `a` in this case?

Comment: FWIW, it's a bad idea to use `sum` as the name of your own function because there's already a built-in function with that name.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
g(5, partial(sum, b=5))
```

> Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func called with the positional arguments **args** and keyword arguments **keywords**. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are **appended** to args. If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they **extend and override** keywords
>
> The partial() is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature. For example, partial() can be used to create a callable that behaves like the int() function where the base argument defaults to two:

```
basetwo = partial(int, base=2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works beautifully.